# Aspect's properties extractor - Alfresco

Tags: java, maven, alfresco, opencmis

I am new to alfresco, I want to create a program that is capable of extracting a custom aspect's properties metadata, I've found people talking about Alfresco opencmis extension but i didn't know how to use it, is there any tutorial i can follow?

Comment: Tonnes! Just google.... What did you try so far?

Comment: i've found this https://github.com/OpenDataSpace/opencmis-extension
i did import it it builds successfully but i don't know how to execute it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, find an actual document using some kind of query and get it's metadata back (including your custom ones)?

Answer (score 2):

You should not need the opencmis extension if you are using a reasonably new release of Alfresco and the CMIS version 1.1 binding. All you need is a CMIS client for your favorite language.

You can take a look at [this project](https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-api-java-examples) for Alfresco Public API examples, keeping in mind that what you want is the on-prem use case, not the cloud use case.

This page also has good resources:
https://www.alfresco.com/cmis